# Compile time polynoms

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, polynomials

I (finally) recently heard about variadic templates. I'd like to know that if there is a way to make a int - polynomial with compile time operators:

```
template <int... coefs> 
struct polynom {}
```

Which coud support add, unary minus and mul operators.

[Edit] : claryfying question:

A int-polynom is basically one integer list (coefficients) :

```
1 + 2x^2 - 7x^5 <=> (1, 0, 2, 0, 0, -7)
```

I'd like this polynom to be represented by a compile time constant:

```
polynom<1,0,2,0,0,-7>
```

Let's first consider addition (in which we add elements one by one).

Is it possible to have somehow an operator+ such that:

```
polynom<1,0,1> + polynom<-1,2,1,3> -> polynom<0, 2, 2, 3>
```

?

For multiplication it would be a similar (but more complex issue).

Does someone here any experience about that?

Comment: Templates are a compile-time mechanism. If you want a polynomial that's evaluated at compile time, you could get away with what you are proposing. It's not possible to use run-time values as template arguments. You would be better off simply taking the maximum degree of your polynom as a single template argument and storing the terms in an `std::array`.

Comment: What's wrong with `polynom<1,2>` being different from `polynom<2,1>`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux : what if my coefficients are compile time constants?

Comment: Yes it is quite easy actually, have you tried anything?

Comment: have a look at [std::integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: @n.m. Fermat theorem is quite easy when you know the proof, but I can't write it in a comment... of course I tried but I don't know variadic templates enough...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with in 10 minutes, probably not the most elegant or efficient solution but quite straightforward one, using only boring bog-standard technique of recursion over the variadic argument list.

```
#include <iostream>

// our polynomials are little-endian: the first coefficient is for power 0,
// the second one is for power 1 etc
// The empty list corresponds to the zero polynomial
template <int ... coeff> struct Poly {};

// Print it out
template <int ... coeff> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Poly<coeff...>);
template <> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Poly<>) { return os; }
template <int coeff0, int ... coeff> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Poly<coeff0, coeff...>) {
    os << coeff0 << " " << Poly<coeff...>();
}

// For number coeff0 and polynomial poly(x), return coeff0 + x * poly(x) 
template <int coeff0, class poly> struct poly_shift;
template <int coeff0, int ... coeff> struct poly_shift<coeff0, Poly<coeff...>>{
    using type = Poly<coeff0, coeff...>;
};

// Addition of polynomials 
template <class poly1, class poly2>
struct poly_add;
template <>
struct poly_add<Poly<>, Poly<>> { using type = Poly<>; };
template <int ... coeff>
struct poly_add<Poly<coeff...>, Poly<>> { using type = Poly<coeff...>; };
template <int ... coeff>
struct poly_add<Poly<>, Poly<coeff...>> { using type = Poly<coeff...>; };
template <int coeff_l0, int coeff_r0, int... coeff_l, int... coeff_r>
struct poly_add<Poly<coeff_l0, coeff_l...>, Poly<coeff_r0, coeff_r...>> {
    using type = typename poly_shift<coeff_l0 + coeff_r0, typename poly_add<Poly<coeff_l...>, Poly<coeff_r...>>::type>::type;
};

// convenient infix operator for values 
template <class poly1, class poly2>
constexpr typename poly_add<poly1, poly2>::type  operator+ (poly1 p1, poly2 p2) { return {}; }

// test it
int main()
{
   Poly <1,2,3> a;
   Poly <3,4,5,6> b;
   std::cout << (a+b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you exactly want (can you propose an example of use?) but I suppose that a way is define a set of types based on `std::integral_constant`.

By example, the unary minus can be defined as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct uminus
   : std::integral_constant<typename T::value_type, - T::value>
 { };
```

and the add operator as follows

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct add
   : std::integral_constant<typename T1::value_type, T1::value + T2::value>
 { };
```

To semplify your expression, you can define a single integer as follows

```
template <int I>
struct i : std::integral_constant<int, I>
 { };
```

so you can write expression (computed compile time) as follows

```
constexpr auto val = add<i<5>, uminus<i<3>>>::value;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct uminus
   : std::integral_constant<typename T::value_type, - T::value>
 { };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct add
   : std::integral_constant<typename T1::value_type, T1::value + T2::value>
 { };

template <int I>
struct i : std::integral_constant<int, I>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto val = add<i<5>, uminus<i<3>>>::value;

   std::cout << val << std::endl; // print 2
 }
```